# Crop Point Cloud with 2D Image Mask

Tags: python, point-clouds, open3d

My goal is to apply a mask of a leaf onto a point cloud of the entire scene so I can have the point cloud of one individual leaf.

I have point cloud data. I can convert it into any format that is most appropriate. Right now I have it as a colored point cloud in a .obj file and I have the same point cloud where each point is defined with [x y z] format in another file. I can make it into a numpy array or anything else that is best suited for this.

However, the point cloud data has the camera as [0 0 0], so values to west and below the camera are negative (This is not the same as the mask)

I have mask data visualized in the following way:
[image]

I can isolate the mask for one leaf. I currently have access to it in a true/false array of shape (1024, 1024, 16) format but I can also modify how this data is organized. However, I don't quite understand the 16 bits? I'm assuming it's 1024 by 1024 pixels? why are there 16 true/false values per pixel? Maybe this doesn't matter, I can assume if there's a true value that pixel is true.

true/false array:

[image]

MY QUESTION:
How do I 'crop' the point cloud to only include the points within those defined by the mask?
This involves:

- How do I convert the formats of the point cloud and the mask to be able to accomplish this?

(I'm using matterport's mask rcnn for the mask and ZED sdk for creating the point cloud, but this doesn't have to matter)